# Different timestamp php and android

Tags: php, android, timestamp

why i get different timestamp on android (firebase servertime) and php ? i use http://currentmillis.com to read its value. (UTC+9h)

on android i got 
**1498500983065**  currentmillis.com output was *Tue Jun 27 2017 03:16:23*

while on php i got **1498500646140** , currentmillis.com output was *Tue Jun 27 2017 03:10:46*

its around 6 minutes apart.

my android time actually nearly as accurate as what currentmilistime shown.

on php i use :

```
$servertime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

where is the problem ?

edit :  i executed the code both only within seconds apart. and several times with the same result.

Comment: It might be a difference between the time set on the server (PHP) and the device (Android). Six minutes is a bit odd, which is why I'm *guessing* that. And are you sure they are sent at the same time?

Comment: yes i am sure, i executed it both within seconds only. i have been tested it several times with same result.

Comment: You can install ntp to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using hostinger as my hosting and the problem solved when i upgrade the plan. the free version give me bad server time.